# Tricky tier exam problem on sequence convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have an old qualifying exam problem that I am having trouble with:

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers and define $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k$.
 Assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n} a_n=1 $ and prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n/\sqrt{n}=2$

If the product of two sequences converges to a positive number and one of the sequences diverges to infinity, does the other sequence have to converge? If so would a_n be decreasing and positive for n large enough?

Comment: Solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h493490p2768625.

Comment: You need the decrease of $a_n$ in order to approximate the sums by integrals, right?

Comment: Thanks to @Martin R, the initial problem has been solved. However, the raised questions remain unclear: If the product of two sequences converges to a positive number and one of the sequences diverges to infinity, does the other sequence have to converge? If so would a_n be decreasing and positive for n large enough?